# How can I remove deleted files from Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

[image]

These are the deleted files in PR.I want to remove them completely.

Answer (score 1):

That pull request appears to do exactly what you want. Simply [accept it](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/work-with-pull-requests-223220593.html#Workwithpullrequests-Acceptapullrequest) (after reviewing it to ensure it has the desired effect, of course).